# Point to CNAME to openshift throws certificate issue

Tags: ssl, dns, openshift, cname

I have my domain CNAME point to `myapp-mynamespace.rhcloud.com` however it throws this certificate error:

[image: SSL Error]

Doing `rhc alias add proxy proxy.mynamespace.com` would do the trick.

However, I just want to point arbitrary domain CNAME (like ww2 of xyz.com, abc.com or somedomain.com) to `myapp-mynamespace.rhcloud.com`

How do I get around this ssl issue, is it possible that when I point ww2 CNAME of xyz.com to my openshift app (myapp-mynamespace.rhcloud.com) it will not do https or ssl thing--just plain http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want a CNAME record, you want a web redirection, else the domain name will remain the one that points to rhcloud.com and the certificate will still be invalid for your web clients.

Comment: why do you suggest "web redirection:?

Comment: Well, I assumed that you wanted to handle web traffic based on your screenshot (I might be wrong though).
The issue is however the same: a CNAME record is an alias, not a redirection. If as a client you request www.somesite.com which is a CNAME to www.google.fr, everything will work except you still would believe you are on www.somesite.com.
The redirection would, well, redirect to the server (in which case the cert would be OK).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SSL with your custom domain on OpenShift then you will need to upgrade to the Bronze or Silver plan and purchase an SSL certificate and install it for your alias.

Comment: If I do this, I will have to purchase SSL for each alias like abc.com and xyz.com? Or Its just SSL for my proxy.mynamespace.com that will solve my problem?